# Golang Initializing multiple prepare statements in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I am planning to prepare multiple SQL statements to a connection to PostgreSQL during the initialization of the application. By preparing these SQL statements, they will be cached in the connection for reusability later which improves performance. However, I am not sure how I can use the SQL statements in a Golang Map to reuse the cached statements later. I have tried to implement it myself but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

```golang
// prepare.go
package dbrepo

var stmts = make(map[string]*sql.Stmt)


func prepareStatements(db *sql.DB) (map[string]*sql.Stmt, error) {
    
    stmts["getAlbumByID"], err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM album WHERE id = ?")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    stmts["addAlbum"], err = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO album (title, artist, price, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    // Add more prepared statements as needed
    
    return stmts, nil
}
```

```golang
package dbrepo

func connect() (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:password@localhost/mydb")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    return db, err
}

func init() {
    stmts, err := prepareStatements(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

```golang
package dbrepo

func getAlbumByID(id int) (*Album, error) {
    var album Album
    err := stmts["getAlbumByID"].QueryRow(id).Scan(&album.ID, &album.Title, &album.Artist, &album.Price, &album.Quantity)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &album, nil
}

func addAlbum(title, artist string, price float64, quantity int) (int64, error) {
    result, err := stmts["addAlbum"].Exec(title, artist, price, quantity)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return result.LastInsertId()
}
```

In this StackOverflow post, it was suggested to use a map if you have multiple statements but the post did not show how to implement it [What's the recommended way to initialize and keep prepared statements in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586578/whats-the-recommended-way-to-initialize-and-keep-prepared-statements-in-go)

Should I follow this article https://go.dev/doc/database/prepared-statements? where it prepares a statement whenever a query is called. But by doing so, the statement will constantly be prepared over and over again, right? and the code seems very long if I have multiple queries to PostgreSQL.